# Rerender React component with new AJAX query parameter values

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component which fetches Ajax data on the initial page load like this:

```
var MyTable = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            rows: [
                ['Something, ' '],
                ['Something else', ' ']                ]
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.get('http://domain.com/api/Orders/from-date/' + fromDate + '/to-date/' + toDate, 
            function(result) {
                var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, {
                    rows: {
                        0: { 
                            1: { $set: result }
                        }
                    }
                });
                this.setState(newState);            
            }.bind(this)
        );
    },

    render: function() {
        return (

            <Table
                rowHeight={50}
                rowGetter={(rowIndex) => {
                    return this.state.rows[rowIndex];
                }}
                rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
                onRowClick={this._onRowClick}
                width={1000}
                height={342}
                groupHeaderHeight={40}
                headerHeight={0}>
                <ColumnGroup label="Products"
                             fixed={true}>
                    <Column label=""
                            width={col1}
                            dataKey={0} />
                    <Column label=""
                            width={700}
                            dataKey={1} />
                </ColumnGroup>
            </Table>

        );
    }
});
MyTable = React.createFactory(MyTable )
React.render(MyTable(),
    document.getElementById('my-table-container')
);
```

My problem is that I cannot rerender the component when the date is changed from the datepicker thus the Ajax date parameter changes and another request with these new values need to be made.

What I've tried:

```
$(function(){
    $("#calculate-orders").on("click",function(){
        fromDate = document.getElementById("from-date").value;
        toDate = document.getElementById("to-date").value;

        React.render(MyTable(),
            document.getElementById('my-table-container')
        );

    })
})
```

But nothing seems to happen. How can I solve this? And can it be done with JavaScript/jsx only, without the need for flux and most importantly, without node.js?

Ps. I'm using FixedDataTable in this example.

Comment: Can't you just tie the datepicker to your component using an event parameter, that way everytime the event is received your component updates state, which will cause your component to re-render.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it'll work? As far as I understand that would only work if there was a parent-child relationship? https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html - but in this case I've built an application in MVC and as I got to know react, I used it more and more for different sections, however the date pickers (from/to date) and select dropdown (language) is not parent react components - they're just plain html markup. :/

Comment: I was thinking have a  component listen for an event, have the datepicker fire an event that the component is listening to, so there is no need for parent child components. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: I found a resource on it here https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html - i'll try to do it when I get home, and update here :)

Comment: Doesn't look like it can be done. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/284 - I also tested it. Couldn't get it working. :/

Comment: I guess there's no way around creating a parent react component. Would have been sweet though if we could rerender them from a JavaScript/jquery click event with the updated data :/

Comment: you need to implement componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method (with the same logic as componentDidMount), and then whenever you rerender just pass the current fromDate and toData as props to MyTable({fromDate:"", toDate: ""})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was as **Furqan Zafar** said (thanks man).

To implement the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method with the same logic and pass the new properties.

```
$.get('http://domain.com/api/Orders/from-date/' + nextProps.fromDate + '/to-date/' + nextProps.toDate, 
            function(result) {
                var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, {
                    rows: {
                        0: { 
                            1: { $set: result }
                        }
                    }
                });
                this.setState(newState);            
            }.bind(this)
        );
```

I had a little problem with it getting TypeError: Can't add property context, object is not extensible - but that was because I originally had created the component with JavaScript and I was rerendering in jsx. It needs to be the same.. eg:

If I did this initially:

```
MyTable = React.createFactory(MyTable)
```

Then this wouldn't work to rerender:

```
React.render(
    <MyTable fromDate={fromDate} toDate="{toDate}"/>,
    document.getElementById('my-table-container')
);
```

But this would:

```
React.render(
    MyTable(
        {
            'fromDate': fromDate,
            'toDate': toDate
        }), document.getElementById('my-table-container')
    );
```